# What kind of cactus is this and why are these black bumps forming on it?

Tags: identification, pest-control, succulents, cactus

Little burnt-looking bumps have been popping up on this cactus and I'm not too sure what to do about it. Can you help me figure it out?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! Can you try to remove a bump or two, or are they firmly connected to the plant? You can always [edit] your post with more details and I suggest you also take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works while you are waiting for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a cactus form the Genus Mammillaria. Not sure of the specific species. This appears to have been grown either low light or too much fertilizer (or both) for quite some time.

The confusing part is that it is nice and green, plants grown in too little light are generally lighter green. It is definitely distorted though. The spines appear to be very weak and thin and are missing in several places (not well attached, perhaps?)

As far as the brown dots, let us know if you can get one off and what is inside. I suspect it is an pest of some sort, but I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: You're right; I was away for a while and I unfortunately left this cactus in an unsuitable position, which is the reason for its poor growth. As for the black spots, it's possible to remove the top black layer and underneath is a sort of gooey red/clear bump. Any ideas what it might be? Is there any hope for the cactus?